# Using multiple contentPlaceHolders in ASP.NET masterpage

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, contentplaceholder

I am creating a website that has different menus in different pages. So i am creating a Master page with 3 content place holders for Page Heading, Menu and Content Respectively. I am not able to create content pages for this master page. Any help would be appreciated. Please forgive me if I have not followed the proper guidelines as I am a newbie.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PTS.Master.cs" Inherits="PTS.UI.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Patient Tracker System</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            font-size: small;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<section id = "main>
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="page">
        <div id="page-bgtop">
            <div id="page-bgbtm">
                <div id="content">
                   <!-- Enter Your Contents Here-->
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderContent" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
                <!-- end #content -->
                <div id="logo">
                    <h1 class="style1"><a href="#">Patient Tracker System</a></h1>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                     <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderPageHead" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

                </div>
                <div id="sidebar">

                    <%--Paste your Customized Menus--%> 
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderMenu" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
                <!-- end #sidebar -->
                <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end #page -->
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <p>Copyright (c) 2012 Patient Tracker System.</p>
</div>
<!-- end #footer -->
    </form>
     </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you dont need to add this place holder `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
`

Answer (score 3):

Anything inside a `ContentPlaceHolder` on your Master Page is default content.  What "default content" means is that if you do not specify contents for that `ContentPlaceHolder` on your child page, the default content will get rendered.  This is useful for reducing code duplication in some situations.

However, you have your entire `<form>` wrapped inside `ContentPlaceHolderMain`, which is not a good pattern.

**Your Master Page looks mostly correct, but you probably want to remove the `ContentPlaceHolderMain` opening and closing tags.**

Then you will be left with the 3 `ContentPlaceHolder`s that you mention in your question.

Also, you have a typo in one of your comment blocks:

```
<%--Paste your Customized Menus--%>
```

Should be this instead:

```
<!-- Paste your Customized Menus -->
```